# Nothing tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Why do we have a [nothing](/questions/tagged/nothing)???

I would say kill it or am I missing some cool language called nothing?

Comment: Seems like it's mostly improperly applied to mean `null` but I'm not sure, are there some languages that have a Nothing construct/datatype/ect?

Comment: I retagged a few where it was really not needed/appropriate.

Comment: We should add some tag info to let people know it's for the VB `Nothing` keyword.

Comment: That tag has the most appropriate tag wiki ever!

Comment: It would be highly appropriate on a Seinfeld stack exchange.

Comment: @TimPost I improved the tag wiki.

Comment: @Rosinante sigh.

Comment: @RepWhoringPeeHaa I'll clean it up tomorrow, I promise.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Having [nothing](/questions/tagged/nothing) is better than having [something](/questions/tagged/something)! Or is it the other way around?

(Although really, I suspect it's because some languages like Visual Basic use `Nothing` when they mean `null`.)

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0x9tb07z.aspx. You're right... What a stupid keyword btw :)

Comment: Visual basic ruins EVERYTHING. Again.

Comment: No, it's that every other language uses `null` when they mean `Nothing`. Frustrating.

Comment: @minitechη "Nothing." is also the answer you could give to "Did you say anything?" You don't reply that question with "Null."

Comment: @mini: `Nothing` in VB.NET is *not* directly equivalent to `null` in, say, C#.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Where is it not?

Comment: @mini: It has quite different semantics than `null` does in C#. It's probably accurate to characterize it as providing a *superset* of the functionality, in that you would use `Nothing` in VB.NET anywhere that you would use `null` in C#, but you can also use `Nothing` in a number of places in VB.NET that you *couldn't* use `null` in C#, and `Nothing` also represents the default value for value types. I'm *sure* there are questions on SO that discuss this. I feel like I've answered one myself, but I'm much too lazy to search... :-)

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Since when is `Nothing` the default value for value types? Um...

Comment: @mini: It implicitly converts to any type in the type system, and it is equivalent to the default value of that type. It's always been that way, since way back in the bad old days of COM-based VB. The following statement is legal VB: `Dim x As Integer = Nothing` The value `x` will be equal to `0`. Contrast that with `int x = null;` which is *not* legal C#. This is only a simple example.

Comment: @TheEstablishment: Wow. I've always used `0` and `*.Empty`. Thanks!

Comment: @mini: Didn't say I recommended it...

Comment: @TheEstablishment: I know, I hate it when people assign `Nothing` to something because it's pointless. But it's good to know. So thanks!